# Jensen-Shanon Divergence for two probability distributions in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

How to calculate js Divergence for two probability distributions in PyTorch?
or how to add two distribution in pytorch?

Comment: Have a look here: https://kornia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/kornia/losses/divergence.html

Comment: @KaushikRoy Well, I have read this, the inputs are two tensors. But I want to input two torch.distribution objects.